# ValueError when using Flag

Tags: python, python-3.x

The other versions of this question does not make sense to me.

**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'quit'**

```
active = True

while active:
    var = input()

    if var == 'quit':
        active = False

    if int(var) < y
    .
    .
    .
```

Original code below..

```
active = True

prompt = ("Please state your age.")

while active:
    age = input(prompt)

    if int(age) < 3:
        print("Free")
    elif int(age) >= 3 and int(age) <= 12:
        print("$10")
    elif int(age) > 12:
        print("$15")
    elif str(age) == 'quit':
        active = False
```

Comment: What are trying to do? What is var? Looks like you were trying to convert 'quit' to integer.

Comment: @LalaLa I forgot a line. Var is supposed to be user input. If user inputs 'quit' then while loop stops.

Comment: int(var) <---- you cannot do this, int() cannot convert 'quit'. You must check if the input a number or not first by using isdigit() or isalpha() for strings.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are trying to make an `int` out of a string that python has no idea how to numerify.

[image]

Perhaps you mean to use `else` in the second statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the type of user input first. You can use try .. catch .. statement. If user input is not integer or quit, a message can be displayed.

```
active = True

prompt = ("Please state your age.")

while active:
    age = input(prompt)
    if age == 'quit':
        active = False
    try:
        val = int(age)
        if val < 3:
            print("Free")
        elif val >= 3 and val <= 12:
            print("$10")
        else:
            print("$15")
    except ValueError:
        print("Input string is not an Integer or 'quit'")
```

Answer (score 0):

The check `if str(age) == 'quit':` must happen *before* any call to `int(age)`. Move that `elif` to the top of the conditional and make `if int(age) < 3` into an `elif`.

Calling `int` on the same string is wasteful, and calling `str` in it is unnecessary. Rather than using a flag, you can simply use `break`:

```
while True:
    age = input(prompt)

    if str(age) == 'quit':
        break
    age = int(age)

    if age < 3:
        print("Free")
    elif 12 >= age >= 3:
        print("$10")
    elif age > 12:
        print("$15")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're casting a `string` to an `int` with `int(var)` and python will give you a `type error` if the `input()` (always type string) isn't a numeric type.

You can use [isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) to check if the `input()` is of numeric type, i.e.
:

```
arg =  input("Type your age\n")
if arg.isdigit():
  # input is numeric, do something with it
  arg = int(arg)
else:
  # input cannot be casted to an integer or decimal
  exit(0)
```

---

> `str.isdigit()`
>   **Return `true` if all characters in the string are digits and there is at
>   least one character, `false` otherwise**. Digits include decimal
>   characters and digits that need special handling, such as the
>   compatibility superscript digits. This covers digits which cannot be
>   used to form numbers in **base 10,** like the Kharosthi numbers. Formally,
>   a digit is a character that has the property value `Numeric_Type=Digit`
>   or `Numeric_Type=Decimal`.

---

Notes:

- Python's [string-methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)
- [Demo](https://trinket.io/python/99a5978a01)